# how to map object into array of objects for selectsearch in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, select, frontend

so i want to map key and value into an array to use as selectsearch options i tried select and it worked by mapping every item alone, now i need to map all data into a single array. how could i do that?

fetching data from api:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  
const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const [students, setstudents] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStudents = async () => {
      try {
        const resp = await Axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
        setstudents(resp.data);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchStudents();
  }, []);
  const classes = useStyles();
  

const courses=students=>{return students.map(student=>[
  <a
  href={`http://localhost:3000/teacher/course/:${student.id}`}
>
  {student.id}
</a>]);
}// tried to map into an array of links not working
```

make dropdown box of select options thats worked fine:

```
 <select
          onChange={e => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}>
      {students.map(student => 
        <option key={student.id} value={student.username}>
          {student.id}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>//worked here
```

when i use selectsearch cant figure out how to map key and value into one single array beacuse selectsearch take options as an array of key and value not like select:

```
<SelectSearch
      name="form-field-name"
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      clearable={this.state.clearable}
      />
      {students.map(student => 
        <options key={student.id} value={student.username}>
          {student.id}
        </options> )} //couldnt figure out how to make the array of options into single constant
```

Comment: Can you add more information please? ...i have this result, but i want to.... Thanks!

Comment: i want to use select but with search bar so i tried selecsearch but the difference it takes options at once not like <option1>,<option2>,<option3>.... so i need a method to map the api data needed into an array of options to give it to selectsearch... thanks for help

Comment: You are using `SelectSearch` wrong, the options should be provided as props to the component. What is that `<options>` tag doing there?  check [the example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-search#quick-example)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const courses=()=>students.map(student=>
  <a
  href={`http://localhost:3000/teacher/course/:${student.id}`}
  >
  {student.id}
</a>);
```

Also if you don't want to create a separate function, then

```
export default function App() {
  const students = [];

  return (
    <div className="App">      
      {students.map(student=>
      <a href={`http://localhost:3000/teacher/course/:${student.id}`}>
        {student.id}
      </a>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```